# Solver VBA hide dialog box, still appears

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I know there are several topics on this, but in my case it doesn't work. I have a macro to iterate through a series of rows, optimising price for every product. I don't want my macro to display the dialog box for every row.

```
Sub MultipleSolver()
Dim i As Integer
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Activate
For i = 5 To 20
SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:="$K$" & i, MaxMinVal:=1, ByChange:="$B$" & i, Engine:=1
SolverAdd CellRef:="$B$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$E$" & i
SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$G$" & i

SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

Cells(i, "L").Value = SolverSolve

Next i

End Sub
```

UserFinish:=True is supposed to omit the dialog box, however it still shows the dialog box for every row. Many thanks!.

Comment: According to this thread, [SolverSolve UserFinish:=True--Solver Results Dialog Box Still Appears](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/solversolve-userfinish-true-solver-results-dialog-box-still-appears.381980/) this might work: `SolverSolve UserFinish:=True` -> `SolverSolve (True)`

Comment: Thanks Wizhi, O solved it with instruction SolverSolve(True), no matter how many times this instruction appears in my code. Again if you post it as an answer I can mark it as a solution.!

Comment: Np!!! So happy it worked for you :D!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way could be to change :
`SolverSolve UserFinish:=True` -> `SolverSolve (True)`

according to the thread [SolverSolve UserFinish:=True--Solver Results Dialog Box Still Appears](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/solversolve-userfinish-true-solver-results-dialog-box-still-appears.381980/)